# Javascript: Strip tags with desired class

Tags: javascript, class, strip-tags

I use this function to stip tags in javascript

```
noTags = result.strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```

but how can i only remove tags if the hay a desired class??

for example, from

Remove only tags with classes: 'tooltip_left', 'tooltip_right', 'tooltip_bottom' and keep

...

Comment: cant you use the document.getElementsByClassName function?

Comment: Or use Jquery if you can. It is very easy to loop through all elements with a certain class. $('.className').each(function(){//remove tags})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this: ([js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xPKRf/))

```
var StripTags = function (desiredClass)
{
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.' + desiredClass);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
        nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]);
}

StripTags("tooltip_left");
StripTags("tooltip_right");
StripTags("tooltip_bottom");
```